# Reloading UITableViewController from outside a function called in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I am using a UITableViewController and need to reload the table within a function. When I run the app the table view is not reloading. I am receiving no errors.

CODE:

```
func loadTheaters() {

    let api = ""
    let theaterId = id
    let date = date
    let url = URL(string: "http://data.tmsapi.com/v1.1/theatres/\(theaterId)/showings?startDate=\(date)&api_key=\(api)")
    print(url!)
    let request = URLRequest(
        url: url! as URL,
        cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
        timeoutInterval: 10 )

    let session = URLSession (
        configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
        delegate: nil,
        delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main
    )

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (dataOrNil, response, error) in
        if let data = dataOrNil {
            do { let filmList = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Films].self, from: data)
                self.films = filmList
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Why is the tableview not reloading?

Comment: Is the call to `reloadData` even being reached? Use the debugger. See what's happening.

Comment: Yes, it's being reached.

Comment: Are `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` being called? Do they return non-zero values?

Comment: Number or rows in section will be updated when the tableView reloads. I don't have a numberofSection's it's defaulted to 1

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Is `numberOfRowsInSection` being called? Does it return a non-zero result?

Comment: I had sections returned to 0. Problem solved.

Comment: check datasource and delegate for ur tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had numberOfSections returned to 0.

Solved:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}
```

Comment: yes, I was also thinking if table data source methods are called/handled properly after `reloadData()` or not

Comment: You could also do `var films: [Films]? {didSet {tableView.reloadData()}}`. I like that better b/c less bookkeeping figuring where the reload comes from.

Comment: If the table has only **one** section, delete the method. `1` is the default.

Answer (score 0):

You should reload tableView in the `main queue`,

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

post this please check your `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` dataSource methods if they are handled properly

Comment: This is not working

Comment: does it call any of the data source methods of table view?

Comment: how are you calling `loadTheaters()` method?

Comment: I'm calling it in viewDidLoad

Comment: how about data source methods? are they called after table view `reloadData()`, and can you please confirm if `self.films` has values

Comment: self.films prints with data. The data from this function is used within cellForRowAt which is why I need to reload the table so it will use this data. I accomplished this in a viewcontroller with a tableview outlet but have had trouble reloading tableviewcontrollers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185281/discussion-between-bappaditya-and-jsharpp).